# How to save correctly new data with working copy approach

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my application every user can **add a new book**. There is possibility to **add a photo of the book**. All fields in form are mandatory but if user wants to finish this form later, **he can save half of form as working copy**. I wonder how I need to build the **working copy** function that will save only new photos of the books and remove old.

```
Entities:
-Book
*Id [PK]
*Title
*Author
*Description
*PagesCount

-BookPhotos
*Id [PK]
*BookId [FK]
*BookPhoto [string base64]
```

I have a couple of ideas, but I need to choose one (or maybe find diffrent) with the best optimization:

1. Every time delete all photos which are connected to the edited Book entity.
2. Try to find the same value in field BookPhoto [base64] and edit only this field in the database.
3. Edit every record in the table (to the new BookPhoto data) that BookPhoto [base64] didn't exist in edit request data.

In my opinion:

1. I wonder if the database wouldn't be angry at me if I will remove and insert a new data into the table with every request. Is there will be any problem with that approach? What if this will do a hundred or thousands of people?
2. This sounds nice but what if edit data won't contain old BookPhoto value? Then I need to remove every record from the table that didn't exist in request edit (working copy) data.
3. I think that there will be a lot of problems with editing and comparing. For example what if the request data will have less photos than exist in table. Which one will be edited with which.

If someone have some ideas how to do this in the correct way I will be thankful.

Best Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Compare `BookPhotos.Id`

Select the BookPhotos of the working-set's Book from the database. For each DB photo:

1. If ID is in working-set, then update the bytes (base64 string in your case)
2. If ID is not in working-set, then delete the photo

For each working-set photo:

1. If ID is not in DB, then insert that photo as new

Alternatively, the web request can specify which records are new, modified, and removed, instead of just supplying the new state of the model. Then you simply perform those actions against the DB.

A con to this is that you are trusting the client. If it says to add an already existing item (primary key) or modify/delete an item that does not exist, of course the DB operation will fail. You decide how to respond to the client in that case, and if you will rollback all operations as a single transaction or allow what worked to be committed.